# LCD Counter and Hour Meter

Tags: lcd, meter

In an electronic board I've found an LCD Counter and Hour Meter.
Here's the technical information.

https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/001a/0900766b8001abd9.pdf

Since it's very expensive, I would like to save some money making it with a custom project (maybe made with a cheap LCD and an Arduino or dedicated micro).

Can I achieve the same results?

Is it so expensive (almost 25$) because it has some advantages or 
 particular characteristics?

Comment: The price of a product isn't always related to its properties but also to supply and demand. And $25 isn't that expensive for an industrial module like that. Yes of course you can make your own. Do realize that if you do not know how to do that it will cost you **a lot of time** to figure that out. So how expensive is your time?

Comment: What is the comparison between the spec sheets of the components they chose and yours?

Comment: Did you notice that it runs from 12 and 24 V DC supplies (common in industrial applications) and, I presume, keeps the hour count during power interruption. By the time you've done all that you'll find that your home-made solution will be the same price and five times the size.